# MongoDB alphabetical sorting bug

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB standard $sort operation and found out that the result gets disrupted if there is a lower upper case string.

Example:

```
Google
HTC
LG
Yoc
iTaxi
```

As you can see the `iTaxi` gets pushed to the bottom, instead of being located after the `HTC`.

Comment: Related issue on mongodb.org: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is case sensitive sorting where lowercase letters come after uppercase letters. Thus, for sorting and searching purposes, it makes sense to store a "normalized field", where strings are all caps and certain special characters are removed or replaced, e.g.

```
[ { name : "iTaxi", searchName: "ITAXI" },
  { name : "HTC", searchName: "HTC" },
  { name : "Ümlaut", searchName: "UMLAUT" },
  .... ]
```

In  this example, the `searchName` field should be indexed, not the `name` field.

The normalization of strings, particularly replacing umlauts and special characters, is a bit tricky. For instance, in German `ü` should become `ue` and `ß` should become `ss` or `sz`, but that is widely out of scope of your original question.